# Update mysql query with reading HTML SELECT

Tags: php, html

I'm making an orderform, just an internal one.

My form can already add a new order and summarize it on the internal page.
Form is made in a table.

Database queries (which are all displayed in the table): ordernr, klantnaam (customername), productnaam (productname), productid, status

Now, I'd like to change the status (with the HTML select option) by.. lets say "Not ordered" to "Ordered". and when I press the submit button it should "update" it in the SQL database.

HTML select list: "Niet besteld, Besteld, Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie, Onderweg naar vestiging, Ontvangen".

How do I do this?

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bestelformulier");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM overzicht");

//table heading

    echo "<table align='center' width='700px' border='2'>
    <tr>
    <th width='10px'>Ordernr</th>
    <th width='10px'>Klantnaam</th>
    <th width='10px'>Productnaam</th>
    <th width='10px'>ProductID</th>
    <th width='10px'>Status</th>
    </tr>"; 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['ordernr'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['klantnaam'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['productnaam'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['productid'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td><select><option>" . $row['status'] . "</option></select></td>";

//end table

    mysqli_close($con);
```

//adding order table

```
    echo "<h5>Bestelling Toevoegen</h5>";
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<table width='700px' border='1'>

    <tr>
      <th>klantnaam</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='klantnaam'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Productnaam</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='productnaam'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>productid</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='productid'/></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
       <th>Status</th>
       <td>
         <select name='status'>
           <option value='Niet besteld'>Niet besteld</option>
           <option value='Besteld'>Besteld</option>
           <option value='Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie'>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>
           <option value='Onderweg naar vestiging'>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>
           <option value='Ontvangen'>Ontvangen</option>
         <select>
       </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Toevoegen'/></td>
    </tr>";


    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";

    $klantnaam = $_POST['klantnaam'];
    $productnaam = $_POST['productnaam'];
    $productid = $_POST['productid'];
    $status= $_POST['status'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO overzicht (klantnaam, productnaam, productid, status)
    VALUES ('$klantnaam', '$productnaam', '$productid', '$status')");

    $current_url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "http://" : "https://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header ('Location: ' . $current_url);
    exit ();
    }



    mysqli_close($con);
```

This is the code I have been using so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u explain exactly..

Comment: what do you want me to explain exactly?

Comment: where are the other options of select ?

Comment: There are two tables, one for adding a new order (which has those options of select) and this table. I'll edit my post and post that one aswell

Comment: while retrieving from database you was not giving any option to select except the value from databse

Comment: could you give me an example of how I should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create a select with all options

change this

`echo "<td><select><option>" . $row['status'] . "</option></select></td>";`

to

```
  echo "<td><select>
  <option>" . $row['status'] . "</option>";
  if($row['status']  != "Niet besteld")
  echo "<option>Niet besteld</option>";
  if($row['status']  != "Besteld")
  echo "<option>Besteld</option>";
  if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie")
  echo "<option>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>";
  if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar vestiging")
  echo "<option>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>";
  if($row['status']  != "Ontvangen")
  echo "<option>Ontvangen</option>";


echo" </select></td>";
```

Comment: Yesssss, thanks a lot krishna! It worked :) will add a submit button myself but you helped me out for the most! Thanks again!

Comment: if you have problems with submit button post it here. i will try to sort it out.

Comment: I've been trying to work on the code, but I can't figure it out. Would you mind assisting me if you can?